# Flexbox flex-direction issue

Tags: css, flexbox, sidebar

I have a problem with flexbox. So i have 1 container and 2 block inside it. I want to set flex-direction to "column" when screen width less than 700px. But i can't. When screen width  less than 700px , none of them aren't showing. :)

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Flexbox</title>
 </head>
<body>
        <div class = "container">

            <div class = "slot_1"></div>
            <div class = "slot_2"></div>

        </div>

 <style>
  *{
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 ;
}
.container{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;

}
 .slot_1{
     background:red;
      flex: 3;
}

.slot_2{
    background:orange;
    flex:1;
}

@media (max-width:700px){
    .content{
        flex-direction: column;
    }

}
 </style>
</body>
```

Comment: The main problem you have is (besides the wrong class name), the `* {
    margin: 0 auto; }` rule. Using auto margin's will break flex items default behavior, so I recommend to remove that, and it will work as you expect: https://jsfiddle.net/p4aco95u/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple issues here:

1. `.content` should be `.container`.
2. You should specify width for the `.slot_1` and `.slot_2`.

Here's working CSS

```
  *{
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 ;
}
.container{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;

}
 .slot_1{
   height: 30px;
     background:red;
      flex: 3;
}

.slot_2{
  height: 30px;
    background:orange;
    flex:1;
}

@media all and (max-width: 700px){
    .container{
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .slot_1,
    .slot_2 {
      width:100%;
    }

}
```

I've added 30px height for demonstration.

Also here is working fiddle with your example:
https://jsfiddle.net/x5h1ohzr/

Answer (score 0):

Your class name in the media query is wrong. It is `.content`, should it not be `.container` ?